# How do I troubleshoot a weird internet issue on my laptop?

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I have a Lenovo laptop running Window 10 which has recently started exhibiting a strange issue with the internet. When I connect this laptop to my home wifi, it is unable to get any speed. This is to the point where [speed test](http://speedtest.net) does not even load fully. Google's speed test tool errors out. Here is what I have tried so far with no luck

1. Using task/resource manager, ensured that there is no other process/programme eating the bandwidth. The Wifi/Ethernet tab on the task manager shows very poor internet speed anyway which confirms the issue
2. Connect the laptop using Ethernet cable to my router. Still the same internet speed
3. Performed IP reset and flush DNS on the laptop
4. Tried changing the DNS to Google DNS
5. Changed the channels on both my 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz networks to the ones that are not used by my neighbours but still the same problem
6. Followed Intel's suggested setting for the best settings for their AC 9560 Wifi kit and still the problem persists
7. Checked the speeds while connected to office Wifi and it's all fine which suggests that there is no issue with the wifi/Ethernet hardware/drivers on the laptop

Note that, there are a number of other devices connected to my home wifi which are absolutely fine. This ranges from smart switches to a Macbook pro and everything in between.

I have recently installed TP-Link's AV2 power adapter which operates its own wifi with a different SSID. I have tried connecting to that Wifi and tried switching off the whole TP-Link kit to rule out if it the powerline adapter at fault. None of this has helped.

I am not expecting an answer but a suggestion for steps and tools I can use to disgnose this issue.

Comment: On your laptop, run TCP/IP Reset and DNS Flush.  
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer. 
Now reset your router and update the firmware in the router. Delete the wireless setup, restart your router again and make a new wireless setup.  See if these two suggestions help.

Comment: @john I have done the ip reset and flush dns which did not help. I will add it to the list above. I will happily give this a try but remember, other devices connected to that router have no issues with speed (reaching upto 100 mbps). Also, the same laptop connected to office network (both wifi and LAN) has no issues either.

Comment: There is something additional apparently wrong with this device. Try running DISM and SFC (corrective repairs). From an admin command prompt run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth . Follow with SFC /SCANNOW .  Restart when done and test. If that fails, try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  This will update most other drivers.

Comment: Use `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces` and see if the MTU should be reduced. The command is `netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface “Ethernet” mtu=1518 store=persistent`.